# Double quotes inside single quotes in oracle statement

Tags: oracle

I'm having the following problem with an old database. We migrated from sql to oracle recently and I'm having trouble with an insert statement where the column name is "default". Any ideas (I'm not allowed to change the column name, that would be by far the best solution!)?

It looks somehow like this, only with a billion more columns and it's inside a large if-when-else construction for validating issues, so I can't drop the execute immediate.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO trytable (ID, "DEFAULT") VALUES (''monkey1'', 0)'
```

Comment: I don't think double quotes inside single quotes is a problem. But are you sure you can have a column named DEFAULT in Oracle (quoted or not)?

Comment: Is the column name `"default"` or `"DEFAULT"` (or any combination of casing)? You have to be _exact_ as you've quoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem comes from your column name, as shown in this working example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE trytable (ID VARCHAR2(10), "DEFAULT" NUMBER);

Table created

SQL> BEGIN
  2     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  3        'INSERT INTO trytable (ID, "DEFAULT") VALUES (''monkey1'', 0)';
  4  END;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Technically, you can have a table column name named `DEFAULT`, even if it's generally a bad idea that will lead to confusion. You will only be able to interact with it through the double-quote `"` syntax because `DEFAULT` is a reserved word.

If you specify double quotes around identifiers, [Oracle will treat them as case-sensitive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#i27570), so you have to make sure that they match the table specs.

In your case, it would help to have the specific error message.

Comment: You were right, problem was with the statement surrounding this block. Apparently Oracle has difficulties telling me where exactly somehting went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The below will executes if your column name is `"DEFAULT"`:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TRYTABLE(ID, "DEFAULT")VALUES(''monkey1'',0)';
END;
```

"DEFAULT" and "default" makes difference.